# Simulation of Pure Aloha Protocol

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, simulation, network-protocols

I am trying to simulate the Pure Aloha protocol. After some research I understood how this protocol works. In a nutshell, assuming we have 5 nodes and frame size is fixed. All nodes  share a single channel. When a node has data to send it sends the data over the channel. If two ore more nodes try to send the frames at the same time (or within the same time frame) the packets collide and each node has to resend the packet again. Collided frames will have to be re-transmitted after a random time which will decrease the probability of colliding again.

This is what I have so far. I have five nodes [A-E]. These are the five stations. Each node has its own list of integers. These are the time when to send the frame. I generate five random frames and I have this result:- E.g. A 5, A 7, B 7, C 8, E 9. These are generated randomly and mean that node a have two frames to send at time = 5 and time = 7. Frame B has one frame to send at time = 7. Since we have two frames that try to send a frames at the same time we have a collision.

Using this code I have the below result...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace Test_v1
{
    public class Simulation
    {
        Utility utils = new Utility();
        static Random random = new Random();
        private Timer t1;
        int currentTime;
        int frameSize;               //frame size in bits.
        int channelCapacity;         //channel capacity in bits.
        int frameTime;               //time to transmit one frame on the channel in milliseconds.
        private List<Node> nodeList;
        Node A;
        Node B;
        Node C;
        Node D;
        Node E;
        int collisions = 0;

        public Simulation()
        {
            frameSize = 10;
            channelCapacity = 100;
            frameTime = (frameSize / channelCapacity) * 100;
            nodeList = new List<Node>();
            A = new Node(); A.stationName = "Station A";
            B = new Node(); B.stationName = "Station B";
            C = new Node(); C.stationName = "Station C";
            D = new Node(); D.stationName = "Station D";
            E = new Node(); E.stationName = "Station E";
            nodeList.Add(A);
            nodeList.Add(B);
            nodeList.Add(C);
            nodeList.Add(D);
            nodeList.Add(E);

            generateFrames(5);

            t1 = new Timer(100);
            t1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(IntervalTimerElapsed);
            t1.Start();


        }


        protected void IntervalTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int framesOnChannel = 0;

            foreach (Node n in nodeList)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n.queue.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (currentTime == n.queue[i])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(currentTime + " " + n.stationName + " " + n.queue[i]);                    
                        framesOnChannel = framesOnChannel + 1;
                        collisions = collisions + 1;
                        if(framesOnChannel > 1)
                        n.queue[i] = BackOff(n) + currentTime;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(currentTime);
                    }

                }
            }
            currentTime++;
            if (framesOnChannel > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Frames on Channel:" + framesOnChannel + " Collision!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Frames on Channel:" + framesOnChannel);
            }

            framesOnChannel = 0;

            if (currentTime > 10)
                t1.Stop();
        }

        private void generateFrames(int load_G)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < load_G; i++)
            {
                Node randomStation = getRandomNode();                
                randomStation.queue.Add(utils.RandomNumber(0, 10));
            }

            foreach (Node n in nodeList)
            {
               n.queue.Sort();       
            }
        }

        private int BackOff(Node node)
        {
            int k = node.attempts;

            if (k > 10)
                k = 10;

            int R = (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow(2, k) - 1);
            int backOffTime = random.Next(0, R) * frameTime;

            return backOffTime + (frameTime * 2);
        }

        private Node getRandomNode(){
        switch (random.Next(1, 6))
            {
                case 1:
                    return A;

                case 2:
                    return B;

                case 3:
                    return C;

                case 4:
                    return D;

                default:
                    return E;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

[image: Output so far]
I have so far managed to detect when there is a collisions. 
a)I need somehow to apply the Backoff method to those Nodes that collide and send them in a future time. I applied the backoff when a collision is detected but nothing happens. In this case all the frames should collide since for a frame to be succesfully trasnmitted there must be only one frame in time of two ticks.

b) I need to count the succefull transmissions. A transmission is sucessfull if no other frame is send within 2 ticks. Example if a frame is send at time = 1. There must be no other frame within time = 1 to time = 3 to be sucesfull.

Thanks in advance for the help. If something is not clear please tell me.

Comment: Start with some code and then ask where you get stuck specifically.

Comment: @user2307236 Your simulation, as you describe it, doesn't simulate pure aloha, but rather something more similar to Slotted Aloha. In pure aloha, there are no time slots and frames can be sent at any point in time. Since that's the case, you either have to simulate frames sent at non-integer times (e.g. 1.521512) or, if you consider your integer simulation times to be short real times (e.g. millseconds), you have to look for collisions for a lot more than one or two ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a single threaded simulation, you have two choices - a **time driven** simulation, or an **event driven** one. The difference between the two being the way in which the *simulation time* (or *simulation clock*) advances. The way in which time advances determines the way in which the simulation operates:

**1. A time-driven simulation**

In a time driven simulation, time runs continuously and is incremented by small, discrete values in a *timing loop*. The timing loop increments the simulation clock and iterates over each of the components of the simulation (e.g. nodes, channels, etc), asking each one whether it *currently* wants to do something.

The simulation components make their decisions based on the current simulation time (passed by the timing loop), and their predefined behavior. For instance, a node might decide to send a packet at simulation times A, B and C.

After completing each iteration, the timing loop advances the simulation time by a fixed small amount and starts over. In this model, to create a good approximation of actual time, the time increments have to be pretty small.

**2. An event driven simulation**

In an event driven simulation things happen because *it's time for them to happen*. Time doesn't advance contentiously, but from one even to the next. In such a simulation each simulation element (a node, a message ,the shared channel etc) generates timed events (say "i need to send a packet at time XXX", or "a message has arrived at time XXX"). The events are placed into a  time-sorted queue, and the *timing loop* de-queues the events one at a time.

Whenever an event is de-queued, it's handled by notifying all relevant entities of the event. For instance, if the de-queued event is "Node A sent a packet to Node B through channel C at time 5", the event is handled by informing channel C of the sent packet. When informed of the event, channel C can, in turn, create events in response. For instance, it can create a new event that says "A message from Node A has been delivered to Node B by channel C at time 6", thus creating a simulation in which it takes messages 1 simulation time units to propagate across the channel (from time 5 to time 6 in my example). These response events are placed back into the queue, and sorted by time.

Next, the timing loop just de-queues the next event and advances the simulation clock to the time of the next event. This way, if no simulation events occur for a long time, the event loop just skips ahead, unlike the time driven simulation.

This is a (usually) better, more efficient way of simulating systems, but it's also slightly more complex.